# Иностранные, иноязычные и заимствованные слова

Tags: лексика

Чем отличается заимствованная, иноязычная и иностранная лексика? Есть ли между этими названиями принципиальная разница и как правильно использовать их в речи?

Спасибо.

Comment: Заимствуют иностранные слова. Поэтому говорить о различии нет смысла. Заимствованная - уже иностранная.

Comment: Мне попалась книга, где все эти понятия имеют совершенно разное толкование. Хотелось узнать, насколько такое понимание распространено среди пользователей языка. Книга называется: Маринова Е.В.  "Иноязычная лексика современного русского языка" (2012).

Comment: К сожалению, онлайн-версию не нашел.Но в книгах по лексикологии дается именно такое определение. Не могли бы вы коротко изложить суть этих понятий согласно этой книге? Было бы интересно узнать, как именно автор различает эти три понятия.

Comment: Там говорится, что иноязычное слово является более общим понятием, чем заимствованное слово. Термин "заимствованное слово" применяется в том случае, если слово полностью освоено языком и утратило признаки иноязычности (школа, лошадь, табак, солдат). Иностранное слово, напротив, сохраняет признаки чужого языка,  и это ясно осознается пользователями (анимация, тур, форвард, спикер).

Comment: Интересно. Лично я бы не стал разграничивать эти понятия. В книгах обычно говорится об освоенности того или иного иноязычного слова  языком.

Comment: А почему не надо разграничивать? Ведь существует словарь   ИНОСТРАННЫХ, а не иноязычных   слов,  а  "заимствованный" несет в себе значение освоенности (хотя слово взято из другого языка, оно приобрело грамматическую форму и фонетику русского языка, да и термина   "иной, чужой" уже нет в названии).

Comment: Мне кажется, это дело терминологии. Я не вижу разницы между "иноязычный'' и ''иностранный''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Иностранное слово - принадлежащее языку иной страны

Иноязычное слово - принадлежащее иному языку. По-моему, совершенно одинаковое значение.Язык иной страны=иной язык.

Если иноязычное(иностранное )слово часто используется носителями нашего языка, оно осваивается ими, адаптируется,испытывает необходимое семантическое и фонетическое изменение. Адаптация под реалии русского  языка является основным признаком, отличающим заимствования от иностранных слов. Иностранные слова сохраняют следы своего иноязычного происхождения. Такими следами могут быть фонетические,орфографические, грамматические и семантические особенности.

Некоторые учёные говорят, что вся иноязычная лексика, употребляющаяся в русском языке, может быть подразделена на две группы:

I. Освоенные заимствования;

II. Неосвоенные заимствования: 1) экзотизмы; 2) иноязычные вкрапления, 3) интернационализмы.

Освоенные - это заимствования, которые пришли в русский язык очень давно и уже не воспринимаются как чужие. Стали "своими" для нас такие слова, как тетрадь, студент и мн. др.

Не освоенные русским языком резко выделяются на фоне русской лексики. Особое место среди них занимают экзотизмы - слова, которые характеризуют специфические особенности жизни разных народов и употребляются при описании нерусской действительности: аул, сакля, джигит, арба и др.

Иноязычные вкрапления: о'кей, мерси, happy end. Многие из них сохраняют нерусское написание, они популярны не только в нашем, но и в других языках. Употребление некоторых из них имеет давнюю традицию, например Alma Mater (лат. "мать кормящая" - название родного вуза).

Интернационализмы - это иноязычные по своей морфологической структуре слова, преимущественно научные и технические термины, образованные из латинских и греческих элементов. Они существуют не только в русском языке, но и о многих языках мира, почему и называются интернационализмами. Например: автомобиль, демократия, философия, республика, диктатура, телеграф, миллиметр, космодром и т.п.

Так что в разговоре все три слова могут употребляться наравне: заимствованные слова - иноязычные по происхождению, иноязычные слова - те, которые пришли из иного языка (или не совсем пришли, не освоились).

А вот если это научный текст, то, конечно, следует отличать заимствованные(освоенные русским языком) и иностранные (не освоенные, но употребляемые в том виде, как пришли)

Comment: Людмила, спасибо за ответ. Значит, Вы полагаете, что иноязычный и иностранный - это синонимы.  Но, кажется, слово "иноязычный" стало употребляться не очень давно, это относительно новое образование. Зачем оно тогда потребовалось? Кроме того,  слова страна/язык не всегда тождественны (например, в одной стране могут быть два государственных языка),  "язык" относится к области лингвистики, что нельзя сказать о  "стране".